# Can any libraries extract picture(s), if any, from an image of a page of text

Tags: java, image-processing, c, ocr

I have jpeg images of pages of text, some of which have pictures within their layout. I don't care about OCR of the text, but I would like to be able to extract the pictures from the page image for further processing.

Think of a magazine. Some pages might not have any pictures in them - it might just be a column or more of text.

Other pages might contain one or more pictures (diagrams, photographs, charts etc). I need to be able to extract this image data for further processing.

Ideally, I'd like a library that I can call using C, C++ or Java (I'm happy with any of those languages), but at a pinch a complete tool (especially if it's open source!)

My research so far has only thrown up OCR tools which discard image data rather than extract it for processing.

Comment: I personally don´t see any way around OCR, as you have to separate text and pictures.

Comment: Are you looking for a paid solution or something available at no cost?  Depending on the structure of the page, some OCR toolkits can automatically decompose the page into text zones and image zones.  Once you have that collection it can be traversed, can stop at the ones flagged as images, and cropped out.  However, some degree of OCR will be necessary to differentiate them.

Comment: At the moment, I’m open to any ideas - commercial or free, open or closed source. And I know that it may be an OCR tool (albeit that I don’t use the character recognition), but so far I haven’t found any tools which can do what I need but which have APIs that I can incorporate into my own software.

Comment: [LEADTOOLS](https://www.leadtools.com/) does have a C [function call](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/main/api/l-autozonebitmap.html) which can flag regions in an MRC image as text, graphic, or table.  Not entirely certain if this is what you're looking for, though.  Do note this toolkit is a commercial product and is closed source.  Also note I work for this company.

Comment: MRC Image?  All I need to be able to do is take an image (jpeg) of a magazine page (as an example) and extract all of the pictures from it (i.e. crop to each region containing an image) and then I can process them individually (likely save them). The images, just to add complication are going to be line art diagrams - so it isn't as simple as just recognising a large block of colour and identifying it as being an image.

Comment: I believe the [L_AutozoneBitmap](https://www.leadtools.com/help/sdk/v22/main/api/l-autozonebitmap.html) call does perform this decomposition, but it only returns where the images are.  They'd need to be cropped out separately.  However, I don't have access to the inner algorithms which determine what parts of an image are text and what's an inline picture.  (Also apologies, I may have used MRC in the incorrect context.)

Comment: Maybe some DJVU converters can do it.